# Null Pointer exception while uploading images from a camera in Android

Tags: android

This is my current code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {


                final Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
                final Intent gallIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                gallIntent.setType("image/*"); 
                final Intent camIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, camIntent);
                pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, gallIntent);
                pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Select Source");

                startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 0);
                if (bitmap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CreatePod.this, "Uploading",
                            "Please wait...", true);
                    //new ImageUploadTask().execute();
                }
            }
        });

    }



    protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){


     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


     if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"camera cancelled", 10000);
         toast.show();
         return;
         }

        // lets check if we are really dealing with a picture

         if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
         {

             Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap b = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                //setContentView(R.layout.main);


                imgView.setImageBitmap(b);
           // save image to gallery
             String timestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
             MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, timestamp, timestamp);

         }

    }
```

This gives the options Gallery and Camera(Actually, it shows an unsupported device in the place of camera. If I click on it, it gives NullPointerException and crashes. Is this the right way to do it? Or should I use PackageManger? If Yes, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking of your code, I think you have a lack of basic android knowledge,

Miss-use of `onActivityResult()`, its a method of Activity class, take out it from onClick()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

}
```

Just check basic android activity's method and how to use them.

Update:

Look at [Android-Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)